achemso package missing label for authors and affiliations
I am writing with the achemso package
We are only two authors from the same affiliation, therefore I wrote:
\documentclass[journal=jpccck, manuscript=article]{achemso}

\author{Author 1}
\author{Author 2}
\affiliation[1]{Affiliation 1}

\title{Amazing Paper}

\begin{document}

\end{document}

Which works fine, but since we both have the same affiliation I think the package by default do not put any label (double dagger etc...). Now the journal is asking to have this label. I tried a few basic things but I don't see a simple way to do it, any ideas?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please extend your code to a minimal working example (MWE).
